# AS3 using PHP to confirm background URL status

Tags: php, actionscript-3, redirect, confirm, confirmation

I'm creating an Adobe Air app for our members. Each time they open the app, I want it to quickly verify their membership status in the background before it allows them to use it. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the WordPress database that would tell me this valuable information.

Would it be possible to open a URL in the background (completely invisible to the user) that pings their member's only page on our site? Currently, if a non-member tries to access that page, it redirects them to a 404 error page. By loading it in the background, would there be a way for my app to tell if it was redirected to the 404 page or not?

That might be a horrible workaround, so any better ideas are completely welcomed.

Comment: What data do you get from the "member" in order to validate its identity? username & password? 
And how do get this data from the user if he doesn't supposed to interact with your app?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a server sided PHP script  which will return "true" or "false" according to a userId:
http://yourdomain.com/isMember.php?userId=XXX

And then you could use the AS3 URLLoader class like so:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://yourdomain.com/isMember.php?userId=" + userId);
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_complete);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

function urlLoader_complete(evt:Event):void {
    if(urlLoader.data == "true")
    {
        trace("A valid member!");
    }
    else
    {
        trace("An invalid member!");
    }
}
```